# Babel translated React still needs JSXTransformer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have a problem with React.

Babel translates this:

```
React.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

to

```
React.render(React.createElement(
        'h1',
        null,
        'Hello, world!'
      ), document.getElementById('example'));
```

This still works fine and shows "Hello World":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      React.render(React.createElement(
        'h1',
        null,
        'Hello, world!'
      ), document.getElementById('example'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Though, if I remove the JSXTransformer script tag, the page does not work. The page stays just empty, console does not log anything.

The problem occurs both in Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will not interpret script tags with a type other than `text/javascript`. When using with JSXTransformer, the script tag's type is changed from `text/jsx` to `text/javascript`. All you need to do is change `type="text/jsx"` to `type="text/javascript"`.